# Python: How to multiprocess my function with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocess

My function `sound_proc.windowing()` cuts some soundfiles in pieces from a directory and saves the chunks to another directory. To cut all files in the directory I iterate with a for loop over all files:

```
# emodb_path_src = source folder with all sound files in it
# 512 = fix integer
# emodb_path_train = destination folder where all the cut files go

files = [l for l in listdir(emodb_path_src)]

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    print(f'File: {index+1}/{len(files)}')
    sound_proc.windowing(f'{emodb_path_src}{file}', 512, emodb_path_train)
```

Unfortunately, this process is very slow since only one processor core is used. I have already tried it with `multiprocessing` and `Pool` but I can't make it work. Would be nice if someone could give me some hints to get it running on multiple cores.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: What is taking the time?  This is probably not a CPU-bound operation, and if you are I/O-bound waiting for the disk, multithreading/multiprocessing is not going to help at all.

Comment: Multiprocessing can still help by allowing multiple files to be loaded and processed concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) Pool for this in combination with starmap. The trick is to create an iterable of iterables, containing all the args for all the function calls like so:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# Precreate the args
args = [(f'{emodb_path_src}{file}', 512, emodb_path_train) for file in listdir(emodb_path_src)]

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    print(pool.starmap(sound_proc.windowing, args))
```

Depending on how I/O bound your problem is, you might also want to try `ThreadPool`. It's simpler to use and in some occassions even faster than `Pool` because it has less overhead to set up. Another added advantage is that they share the same GIL so you can access the same variable space. Here's a snippet, notice the difference is only a new import and the with statement:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool # thread-based Pool

# Precreate the args
args = [(f'{emodb_path_src}{file}', 512, emodb_path_train) for file in listdir(emodb_path_src)]

# If it's very I/O bound it might even be worthwhile creating more threads than CPU count!
with ThreadPool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    print(pool.starmap(sound_proc.windowing, args))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a good solution for the problem. The code von Gerard works also like charm. I would like to show you briefly how I have solved it now and what time savings you get with the different methods.

**Plain for-loop from the original post:**

Computation duration: *~ 457.7 seconds*

```
files = [l for l in listdir(emodb_path_src)]

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    print(f'File: {index+1}/{len(files)}')
    sound_proc.windowing(f'{emodb_path_src}{file}', 512, emodb_path_train)
```

**Solution provided by Gerard:**

Computation duration: *~ 75.2 seconds*

```
import multiprocessing as mp

args = [(f'{emodb_path_src}{file}', 512, emodb_path_train) for file in listdir(emodb_path_src)]
    
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    pool.starmap(sound_proc.windowing, args)
```

**Using joblib.Parallel:**

Computation duration: *~ 68.8 seconds*

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing as mp

Parallel(n_jobs=mp.cpu_count(), backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(sound_proc.windowing)
                                                    (
                                                        sound_file=f'{emodb_path_src}{file}',
                                                        window_size=512,
                                                        dest=emodb_path_train
                                                    ) for file in files)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about joblib. I added one other option to my original answer, that you could try, though I think in this case it would be slower